# DELETE in mysql using PHP not working

Tags: php, mysql, where-clause, sql-delete, clause

I'm using php to delete a row from a table in a database in mysql, but it's not working. I'm not even trying to do anything fancy, just delete one row. Here's the code:

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM feed WHERE feed = '$feed'") or die("Query failed! with '$feed'");
```

This just doesn't work while this does

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM feed WHERE feed = 'hello'") or die("Query failed! with '$feed'");
```

Please help me...

Complete code (based on comment below):

```
$feed = $_POST['feed'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
echo $feed;
echo $date;
echo $time;
//$r = mysql_query("DELETE FROM feed WHERE date = '$date' AND time = '$time'") or die("Query failed! with '$feed'");
$r = mysql_query ("DELETE FROM feed WHERE feed = '" . mysql_real_escape_string ($feed) . "'") or die ("Query failed with {$feed} and mysql error: " . mysql_error); )
```

Comment: Its a varchar...some text including numbers and special characters

Comment: To debug this, I recommend you echo (or vardump) the contents of the query string, set a variable equal to the SQL text. e.g. `$sql = "SELECT ... "; echo $sql; $r= mysql-query($sql);`  I strongly suspect that there are "special characters" which need to be escaped, or the length of the string exceeds the maximum length of the column. Less likely, there may be an issue with characterset conversion. But these are just guesses. (If this is new development, use mysqli_ or PDO instead of mysql_ interface.)

Comment: sorry i don't know either one of them...

Answer (score 1):

For debugging purpose, print [`mysql_error`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php) to get better idea on what's causing the error.

My guess is that your `$feed` might contain single quote. Get around that with [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

```
mysql_query ("DELETE FROM feed WHERE feed = '" . mysql_real_escape_string ($feed) . "'") or
die ("Query failed with {$feed} and mysql error: " . mysql_error());
```

On a side note, mysql extension is deprecated, so you might want to consider mysqli or PDO.

Comment: Its still not working ... i don't know what the problem...
here is the entire code
'code'

Comment: Are you sure $feed variable is not blank?

Comment: Its still not working
here is the entire code @Sutandiono
'code'
($feed = $_POST['feed'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$time = $_POST['time'];
echo $feed;
echo $date;
echo $time;
 
//$r = mysql_query("DELETE FROM feed WHERE date = '$date' AND time = '$time'") or die("Query failed! with '$feed'"); this one works but not in the way i want
$r = mysql_query ("DELETE FROM feed WHERE feed = '" . mysql_real_escape_string ($feed) . "'") or die ("Query failed with {$feed} and mysql error: " . mysql_error);
)

If it helps,
$feed is a varchar.

Comment: no its not blank .. i used echo() and it shows the feed just fine.

Comment: Can you post the output from `mysql_error`? Also, which line worked but not in the way you wanted? I couldn't figure out from the comment above

Comment: '<?php
 $cn = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 $submit = mysql_select_db("login_form",$cn);

 $feed = $_POST['feed'];
 $date = $_POST['date'];
 $time = $_POST['time'];
 echo $feed;
 echo $date;
 echo $time;
 
 //$r = mysql_query("DELETE FROM feed WHERE date = '$date' AND time = '$time'") or die("Query failed! with '$feed'");
 $r = mysql_query ("DELETE FROM feed WHERE feed = '" . mysql_real_escape_string ($feed) . "'") or
  die ("Query failed with {$feed} and mysql error: " . mysql_error);
?>'

Comment: i have uploaded the entire code in the main post...the line that is commented out is the one that's working but it deletes all the feeds that has same date and time.

Comment: How does it fail? Did you mean the record was not deleted from database, or was there an SQL error? If there is an error, could you post the output of `mysql_error`? Also, if you simply run the query inside your SQL client, will it work?

Comment: Record wasn't deleted..it just says that record was not found but in SQL client it works just fine

Comment: Can you post the content of `$feed`?

Comment: okay..its words like "Hey" or "Nice Weather", "Good morning"..nothing special just good old words!

Comment: Sorry, my suggestion for error checking with `mysql_error` should've been `mysql_error()`. Anyway, I am quite stumped as you are and not sure what happened or how to proceed. I tried something similar locally and it works. Hopefully someone else can shed a light on this matter.

Comment: I am having this same exact problem, my delete query works in phpmyadmin but not in the php file. Did you ever figure it out? If so please share!

Answer (score 0):

Try this... add the curly braces around your $feed variable

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM feed WHERE feed = '{$feed}'")
```

Comment: this one also doesn't work for me @Becs Carter
'code'
mysql_query("DELETE FROM feed WHERE feed = '{$feed}'")
'code'

If it helps $feed is varchar

Answer (score 0):

When you say varchar, is this a fairly long string that contains maybe a URL?

If the string contains any backslashes these will be interpreted as escape characters. Also, you should never run a sql query directly from a POST variable without cleaning it with mysql_real_escape_string().

Also make sure the $feed var doent have any trailing spaces with trim($feed);

Comment: it is very long...its a varchar(2000)